# Update MySql Table with information from another and same table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

We have a couple of tables in out database.
First we have the Extensions table which holds (among other things) the `CustomerId` and the `ExtensionId`

In addition we have a table called `ExtensionCallCenters` which currently only holds two columns: ExtensionId and CallCenterId

I've been tasked with adding a column to this table for the `CustomerId`.
I can get the CustomerId from the Extensions table with a simple LEFT JOIN statement:

```
SELECT Extensions.CustomerId 
FROM ExtensionCallCenters 
LEFT JOIN Extensions ON Extensions.ExtensionId = ExtensionCallCenters.ExtensionId
```

But I cannot update the table with this information.
I've already read through a couple of threads here on SO so I already know that I need to do something with an INNER JOIN.

I've tried this:

```
UPDATE ExtensionCallCenters AS t1 
INNER JOIN ExtensionCallCenters AS t2 
SET t1.CustomerId = ( SELECT Extensions.CustomerId 
                      FROM t2 
                      LEFT JOIN Extensions ON Extensions.ExtensionId = ExtensionCallCenters.ExtensionId
                     )
```

But this gives me an error that `t2` does not exist. If I change the `t2` in the subquery to the original `ExtensionCallCenters` then MariaDB tells me that I cannot update the table with the same table.

Does anybody have an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). provide complete sample and desired final data state.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer but not quite sure how this working.
For anyone who is looking for the same answer:
`UPDATE ExtensionCallCenters AS t1 INNER JOIN ExtensionCallCenters AS t2 SET t1.CustomerId = (SELECT CustomerId FROM Extensions WHERE ExtensionId = t1.Extension)`